# Python - Find name of a folder based on a part of it's name

Tags: python

basically I have a structure like  "myapp/installed_application_10101010/", however, the number of that folder will change regularly.

Therefore I need a way to find this folder everytime. Almost similar to how unix works when you press tab in the terminal, it'll autofill the rest of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module for this.

```
import glob

possible_folders = glob.glob('myapp/installed_application_*/')
# returns ['myapp/installed_application_10101010/']
```

The method returns a list because there could be multiple matches.